# How do I solve for y in $y=\text{tanh}(\frac{x}{y})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, hyperbolic-functions

I want to solve the following equation as a function of purely $x$:

$$y=\text{tanh}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$

My best guess up to this point has been to rearrange the equation using inverse hyperbolic tangent

$$x = y\text{tanh}^{-1}(y)$$

and plugging in the definition for hyperbolic tangent from Wolfram Mathworld

$$\text{tanh}^{-1}(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\text{ln}(1+z)-\text{ln}(1-z)\right]$$

Which I've taken as far as

$$e^{2x}=\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right)^y$$

But seems like a dead end. Any insight into this problem is super appreciated!

Comment: Seriously updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have an explicit solution for a transcendental equation such as
$$y=\text{tanh}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$ Remember that this is already the case for the simpler $y=\cos(y)$.

So, only numerical methods or approximations are possible.

**For small values of $x$**

Rewriting the equation as $$x=y \tanh ^{-1}(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{y^{2n}}{2n-1}$$ we can truncate the infinite series to some order and inverse it. This would give
$$y=\sqrt x \Big[ 1-\frac{x}{6}-\frac{x^2}{360}+\frac{11 x^3}{5040}+\frac{1357
   x^4}{1814400}+O\left(x^5\right)\Big] \tag 1$$

Below are some results.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation} &\text{solution}\\
 0.00 & 0.000000 &  0.000000 \\
 0.25 & 0.479098 &  0.479098 \\
 0.50 & 0.647916 &  0.647918 \\
 0.75 & 0.757421 &  0.757439 \\
 1.00 & 0.833486 &  0.833557 \\
 1.25 & 0.887065 &  0.887249 \\
 1.50 & 0.924563 &  0.924888 \\
 1.75 & 0.950536 &  0.950841 \\
 2.00 & 0.968711 &  0.968364
\end{array}
\right)$$

This seems to be acceptable for rather small values of $x$ (say $x \leq 0.75$). In any manner, for $x > 2.5$, the formula would lead to $y >1$ which is not acceptable.

You could also have some nice approximations using $y_0=\sqrt x$; the first iterate of Newton method is
$$y_1=\frac{2 \sqrt{x}+\sinh \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)}{3+\cosh \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)} \tag 2$$ which, for sure, is less accurate than the above.

Much better would be to use $y_0=\left(1-\frac{x}{6}\right) \sqrt{x}$
$$y_1=\frac{(x-6) \left((x-6) \tanh \left(\frac{6 \sqrt{x}}{6-x}\right)-6 \sqrt{x}
   \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{6 \sqrt{x}}{x-6}\right)\right)}{(x-6)^2+36
   \text{sech}^2\left(\frac{6 \sqrt{x}}{x-6}\right)}\tag 3$$

Reinjected in the original equation and expanded as series of $x$ around $x=0$, we have for the remainders
$$R_{(1)}=\frac{2593 }{11975040}x^{11/2}\qquad R_{(2)}=\frac{1}{36}x^{5/2}\qquad R_{(3)}=\frac{1}{129600}x^{9/2}$$

**For large values of $x$**

In this case, making the expansion of
$$\frac 1 y\text{tanh}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)$$ around $y=1$, we have
$$\tanh (x)+(y-1) \left(-x+x \tanh ^2(x)-\tanh (x)\right)+(y-1)^2 \left(x^2 \tanh
   ^3(x)-x^2 \tanh (x)+2 x-2 x \tanh ^2(x)+\tanh (x)\right)+O\left((y-1)^3\right)$$ and series reversion leads to
$$y=1+\frac{1-\tanh (x)}{-x+x \tanh ^2(x)-\tanh (x)}+$$ $$\frac{(1-\tanh (x))^2 \left(-x^2 \tanh ^3(x)+x^2 \tanh (x)-2 x+2 x \tanh ^2(x)-\tanh
   (x)\right)}{\left(-x+x \tanh ^2(x)-\tanh (x)\right)^3}+\cdots$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{approximation} &\text{solution}\\
 1 & 0.842391 &  0.833557 \\
 2 & 0.968389 &  0.968364 \\
 3 & 0.995196 &  0.995196 \\
 4 & 0.999333 &  0.999333 \\
 5 & 0.999909 &  0.999909 \\
 6 & 0.999988 &  0.999988 \\
 7 & 0.999998 &  0.999998
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: That's a great answer, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to make another answer since it uses a different approach.*

Rawrite the problem as
$$x=z \, \tanh(z) \qquad \text{with} \qquad z=\frac x y$$ If you plot the rhs, it is almost a straight line with a slope very close to $1$ as soon as $z > 1$ (for example, for $z=10$ the derivative of the rhs is $1.0000000783$.

So, make a single iteration of any iterative method (Newton, Halley, Hoseholder, ...) with $z_0=x$.

Using $c=\cosh(x)$ and $s=\sinh(x)$, depending on the order of the method
$$z_{(2)}=x+\frac{c x (c-s)}{c s+x}$$
$$z_{(3)}=x+\frac{x \left(-c^3+3 c^2 s-3 c s^2+c+s^3+s\right)}{4  (c-s)x^2+8 c x +c \left(c^2+3 s^2-1\right)}$$